# Raspberry pi connected with Android phone via web server

Tags: java, android, python, webserver, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to build an application for my phone that receives data from Raspberry Pi (sensor states, etc). I want to develop a web server on my Raspberry Pi to receive information about the sensors and I do not know what is the best way to do that. What is better to use: Java as REST Services, Sockets, ServerSockets or Python? Then I want to connect from android device to that server and display some information.

Comment: yes.... that is the answer

Answer (score 0):

That depends a little bit on the real use case.
If you want a streaming of the sensor data from server to client then use websockets. If you want a request-response functionality (request once and respond with a bunch of data) then use REST. Like the previous poster i would recommend node.js anyway.

Maybe you can look at this http://einaros.github.io/ws/ for websockets and this http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/ for REST